# How to make integration tests between asp.net core web apis?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing

We have Asp.Net Core Web API which calls internally Web APIs B and C in other repositories.

We want to make integration tests in Web API A which confirm that it is connected correctly to B and C.

Option 1 – We move them in the same repository and start programmatically in the memory A,  B and C with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory and this way integration tests are done.

Option 2 – We create mock websites for B and C  and we host them somewhere,  we start in memory only API A with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory, which uses configuration to connect to the mocked B and C and this way integration tests are done.

What is the best way to make integration tests?

Comment: Integration test is a quite blurred term, when you say that you want to confirm connection correctly, could you develop what a correct connection is? and why do you want it do be done in Web API A?

Comment: @joelwsaury We want to be sure the arguments we pass in the httprequest match the parameters of the endpoint. We are new to integration testing and want to make it as useful as possible.